# How to remove yellow blotch from MINWAX Stainable Wood Filler on pine wood

Tags: wood, finishing, staining

Before staining the pine wood siding of my balcony, I used MINWAX stainable wood filler to cover nail holes and knot cracks.

The holes are filled alright, but there is a yellow blotch where the excess product was. Sanding (120 grit) does not make it go away, the wood is stained.

Unfortunately, thinking this product was like plastic wood (which does very well on pine, after sanding, only the hole shows with the filler), the job is done and now I have patches of yellow blotches everywhere.

What should I do to get rid of this?

You can be sure I won't be using this product on pine again.

Comment: A lightly dampened rag should work.  I find it hard to believe that sandpaper would not remove it.  Did you put tons on?  Did you scrape the excess off when you applied it?

Comment: I put a quantity equivalent to the width of my 1" spatula and removed the excess. The wood seems stained by the liquid in the product itself. I guess I am not sanding hard enough. A dampened rag seems a very lite solution but I'll try.

Comment: Try some "Goof Off" on a small area.

Comment: I succeeded in removing the blotches by using an electrical sander. Hand sanding was not working. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I used an electrical sander and the blotches were sanded away. Hand sanding was not hard enough to remove the stain (or fast enough to show a result).

Answer (score 0):

Minwax makes a type of stain in a [marker](http://www.homedepot.com/h_d1/N-5yc1v/R-100376125/h_d2/ProductDisplay?catalogId=10053&langId=-1&keyword=minwax%20stain&storeId=10051) form

[image: stainmarker]

Pick one or two colors closest to your overall finish. These can be blended, but are very very fast drying so wipe with a paper towel quickly to blend and minimize staining. You can also put down a small dot of color and then quickly blend it with the grain. If you have to select a color not nearly identical to the underlying stain, go a little darker.